# How to specify SCSS file contents inline, directly in the component's TS file in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, decorator

In my component I've got the decorator like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: "stuffy",
  templateUrl: "./stuffy.html",
  styleUrls: ["./stuffy.scss"]
}) export class Stuffy { ... }
```

In on occasion, the component is so tiny that three files is way too excessive for it. In such case, I can pull in the template and styles into the class' decorator [like this](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

```
@Component({
  selector: "stuffy",
  template: "...",
  styles: [...]
})
```

However, I can't get it to work if the referred SCSS file contains imports. And my SCSS file looks quite like this.

```
@import "global.scss";
@import "specific.scss";
```

In this case, I get an error saying that:

> Unhandled promise rejection: Failed to load global.scss

Goolearching leads to much more generic solutions than that I'm helped by. I wonder if it's at all possible to pull in SCSS file's contents inline to the decorator if those aren't purely pure CSS statements.

Comment: I'm not sure if any options exist, and this will also depends on your toolchain. But that would be incorrect, at least. `styles` expects CSS, and SCSS is given instead. If a piece of code is supposed to be post-processed with Webpack loaders, it should reside in a separate file.

Comment: Have you checked the path of global.scss, seems like it will look for global.scss in current folder or in node modules.

Comment: @estus Is there an option to specify SCSS contents like we can with CSS in the component's decorator? I mean **without** preprocessing and all that  junk that complicates the process. I mean, I'm specifying SCSS file in `styleUrls` already so it's natural to expect to be using that SCSS for everything else.

Comment: @JorawarSingh Not sure how to verify that. I put all the files in the same directory - all the TS, SCSS and HTML in a one, huge, scary pile. Still getting the same error...

Comment: SCSS is based on preprocessing. It isn't supported by browsers. Unless the framework does this kind of preprocessing directly (and it doesn't), this should be handled by Webpack/Rollup. And they handle this with loaders. This would likely be possible with custom TS loader, but if it exists, I'm unaware of it.